# BC30456 Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, debugging

NET and i have this error i looked online and have tried fixed it for about a day now. Im very new and any help would be great!

```
   Public Shared ReadOnly Property AssemblyDirectory As String
        Get
            Dim codeBase As String = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase
            Dim uriBuilder As UriBuilder = New UriBuilder(codeBase)
            Dim path As String = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uriBuilder.Path)
            Return path.GetDirectoryName(path)
        End Get
    End Property
```

Error I am getting

> Error BC30456 'GetDirectoryName' is not a member of 'String'.

Any help would help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What has happened is that because you have a string variable named `path` it is trying to get a property/method of the string `path`. Notice how it did not capitalize it to `Path`.

You can either change the name of the variable or use `IO.Path.GetDirectoryName`. I would do the former.